# LDAP export attributes based on a different schema or import only valid attributes

Tags: ldap, ldif

I'm trying to export LDAP data from a Zimbra schema into a basic OpenLDAP schema. Obviously the Zimbra schema has much more attributes than the basic OpenLDAP. My question is if there is a way of:

- Either export the LDAP data filtering only attributes present on the basic OpenLDAP schema
- Or having a full export of the LDAP data with Zimbra attributes, somehow import only the valid attributes
- Or if there is a tool to modify the LDIF file to remove the attributes not present in the basic OpenLDAP schema

The LDAP has a few hundred of nodes, so I was looking for a way to make this at least semi-automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, it should be possible to add the Zimbra specific schema to any LDAP server and just import the LDIF file in the usual way.
- Second, you can use the `-c` switch of `ldapadd` to continue operations in case of errors (and the `-S` switch to log this stuff). Obviously, you need to test if you still have a usable structure when doing this.
- Third, if you need only a subset of fields, you can dump only the attributes you are interested when using `ldapsearch`.

See the respective man pages.